# Time out Exception whiling accesing web service(wcf)

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have an webservcie written  it works  fine  . but some time i get this message  error telling  time outexception was unhandled

[Time out Exception](http://cid-3dbfac44f49def30.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/New%20album/time.JPG)

how can i  increase  time  for accessing  the webservice  for the application. is there any setting need to be done.

please let me  know. if any one  knows the  silution  for it

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know for a fact it's a huge data set you're calling, a timeout usually suggests a different problem. The client not locating the service or perhaps an authentication issue.

If it is a large dataset here's config to change the settings
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/360f7997-82f8-40d0-8fd5-8cbbf1c44534

Also be aware, WCF has a maximum message size of 64k by default, but it can be adjust up to a few gig if necessary.